# Measure of compact sets $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ given that $m(C_{1} \cap (C_{2}+x)) = m(C_{2} \cap (C_{1} + x))=0$ for any real number $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to solve the following question in the context of another problem.

Suppose that $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $C_{1}, C_{2}$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $C_{1} \subseteq E$, $C_{2} \subseteq E^{c}$ and $m(C_{1} \cap (C_{2}+x)) = m(C_{2} \cap (C_{1} + x))=0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure). Then, is it true that either $m(C_{1})=0$ or $m(C_{2})=0$?

I have been thinking about this for a while and I attempted to prove it by assuming that $m(C_{1}) >0$ and then trying to conclude   that $m(C_{2})=0$ via the continuity of the real-valued function that maps every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ into $m(C_{1} \cap (C_{1}+x))$ and the fact that $m(C_{1} \cup (C_{2}+x)) = m(C_{2} \cup (C_{1}+x)) = m(C_{1})+m(C_{2})$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (which is implied by the condition $m(C_{1} \cap (C_{2}+x)) = m(C_{2} \cap (C_{1} + x))=0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$). My intuition tells me that since we can guarantee that $C_{2}+x$ will intersect $C_{1}$ for an adequate real number $x$ and $m(C_{1}) >0$, then the fact the equalities $m(C_{1} \cap (C_{2}+x)) = m(C_{2} \cap (C_{1} + x))=0$ hold for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a very strong condition that will imply that $m(C_{2})=0$ but I haven't really gotten anywhere besides those intuitive thoughts. Maybe the answer to the question is negative and there is a pathological counterxample with the fat Cantor set or something like that?

Any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.